# W3 school lightbox jquery add keybinds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, w3c

I am trying to add keybinds to the exemple lightbox ([link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp))
But as much as I try I can't get it to work. Anyone that has any ideas?

I know that I have to do it in JS And I know the keycodes for Left and Right. But I am quite new to JS and I don't understand where I should do the function and how I would make it connect to next/prev.

Then I would like to be able to get ESC to function as a close as well.
Any help would be appreciated.

The original version:

```
function plusSlides(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
```

My version so far, don't know if I am on the right track:

```
function plusSlides(n) {
            window.onkeydown = keydown;
            function keydown(e){
                if(e.which == 37 && next)
            }
            showSlides(slideIndex += n);
        }
```

Got the idea from the original text:

```
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
```

With help from this community:

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   if(e.keyCode === 39) {
       showSlides(slideIndex +=1);
   } else if(e.keyCode === 37) {
       showSlides(slideIndex -=1);
   } else if(e.keycode === 27) {
      closeModal();
   }
```

};

Strangely enough will not escape work. I have tried with keyup as well.

Comment: "if(e.which == 37 && next)" should be followed by a statement and that is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if(e.keyCode === 39) {
        showSlides(slideIndex +=1);
    } else if(e.keyCode === 37) {
        showSlides(slideIndex -=1);
    } else if(e.keyCode === 27) {
        closeModal();
    }
};
```

This works, it can't go inside a function because you want to capture the actual keypress all the time. You'll also want to do something like make sure the modal is actually open before even capturing the keypresses, otherwise every time someone types a key on your site this code runs.

For the record 46 is the period, 44 is the comma

Comment: I have tried your version and it works with just period and comma, but when I try to use other keys. It will not work. I have tried with 37, 39 and even 27. But it will not work..

Comment: Yeah, sorry it should have been onkeydown, try it now. I edited the answer

Comment: Now 37 and 39 worked. But how would I get Escape to work? It says that is 27 for Escape, but when add another line of code that is exactly like else if statement and put 27 with closeModel() as the event for it. It will not work.

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me, see updated answer, is that what you did? I tried it in their editor and it works.

Comment: I found what the problem was. A little c in code.. So it was keycode instead of keyCode... lol